# Can anyone help me to understand why i have the error "list index out of range"?

Tags: python, indexing, range, out

I'm facing an issue trying to sum all the elements of a list in python without using the sum() function.
So, the thing is, when i run my code i'm able to get the desired result, but below appears this error

> IndexError: list index out of range

This is my code:

```
numbers = [4,8,3,1,-3,3,-5,1,2,-8]
sum = numbers[0]
i = 0
for number in numbers:
    i = i + 1
    sum = sum + numbers[i]
    print(sum)
```

According to the error message, the problem is in line 6, but i don't understand what's the problem.
If anyone could help me, i'll appreciate it.

Comment: `i` goes past the end of your list, and then you try and use it as an index in your list. Why don't you use add `number` to your total and forgo `i` altogether?

Comment: You need to do `i = i + 1` *after* you access `numbers[i]`

Comment: Do not use `sum` as a variable. The fact that it is highlighted differently than your other variables should be a tip off that it's bad practice.

Comment: Think about what happens on the last iteration, `i = i + 1`. What will be the value of `i`? it will be `10`. But `10` is out of bounds for a list with length 10, since lists are 0-indexed. Note, messing with indices is pointless. You **already have `number`** since you are iterating over your list

Comment: Trace your code.  Just before line 6, insert a `print` to check `i` and the list length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` before you use it, so its values go from 1 to `len(numbers)` instead of 0 to `len(numbers)-1`.

Instead of indexing into the list, you can use the `number` variable declared in your loop. That variable takes on the value of each element in the list you're looping over.

```
for number in numbers:
    total = total + number
    print(total)
```